# Ajax request without jquery

Tags: javascript, ajax

How to get a data.json

> {"key1":"val1","key2":"val2"}

with a function

```
var getJSON = function (url) {
    var response = null;
    return (function () {
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open('get', url, true);
        xhr.responseType = 'json';
        xhr.onload = function () {
            response = xhr.status == 200 ? xhr.response : xhr.status;
        };
        xhr.send();
    })();
    return response;
};
```

That the code

```
console.log(1);
console.log(getJSON('http://localhost/myproject/data.json'));
console.log(3);
```

gives

```
1
{"key1":"val1","key2":"val2"}
3
```

?
Now it gives

```
1
null
3
```

Thank you

Comment: run your console logs in the callback after assigning response.

Comment: or you can use a promise: https://www.promisejs.org/ or for ES6 https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise

Comment: You're are runing asynchronous request and this is taken out of te normal execution flow. You should use callback or promises. Chek this [stackoverflow question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/)

Answer (score -1):

Using promises.

Create the promise (check the second line in the code block below):

```
var getJSON = function (url) {
    return new Promise(function(){
        var response = null;
        return (function () {
            var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xhr.open('get', url, true);
            xhr.responseType = 'json';
            xhr.onload = function () {
                response = xhr.status == 200 ? xhr.response : xhr.status;
            };
            xhr.send();
        })();
        return response;
    })
};
```

Use `.then` syntax to console.log

```
console.log(1);
getJSON('http://localhost/myproject/data.json').then(function(response){
    console.log(response);
    return;
});
console.log(3);
```

It is gonna print 1,3 and then your data, synce the ajax call is async.

For reference: http://eloquentjavascript.net/17_http.html
or official docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise

Comment: You never call `succeed` or `fail`.

Comment: My point was that you *have* to call them at some point. Otherwise the promise is never going to be resolved or rejected. Simply copying the OP's code inside the promise callback doesn't magically solve the problem. Look at the examples you linked to.

Comment: I want to such getJSON that returns the value and that is usable to aply in var resp = getJSON (url); in right time.

Comment: @user2301515: You want something that is impossible. Don't fight the asynchronous nature of JavaScript, embrace it.